# I can't connect to wifi, it doesn't recognize the network card

Tags: wifi

I can't connect to the wi-fi network, it doesn't recognize my wi-fi card.
The problem is that my laptop does not have an ethernet cable, it does not have the rj45 port

Comment: Is it a new installation or did it stop working ? Which laptop is it ? Which version of  elementary OS ?

Answer (score 1):

This could be the absence of a network manager install it and tell me how it goes. If it is installed restart it. If that doesn't work either, try the command `rfkill list sudo rfkill unblock all`.
The rfkill would tell us if the radio kill switches are blocking the connection.